# how to detect and count pills (capsules)

Tags: android, opencv, hough-transform

i would like to know which algorithm is used to detect pills and capsules? That is detect the number of capsules on a table using opencv and android.

**The procedure i have used:**

first capture the image and we apply grayscale then apply thresholding after thresholding i applied erosion then after using houghcircles i try detecting capsules but not able to detect any capsules.

please give solution.....

**What i have tried so far:**

[image]

[image]

this is my code to detect pills in android opencv.

```
        Bitmap i = getBitmap(imgPath + "orignal.jpg");

        //Log.i("after Bitmap i",""+imgPath);
        Bitmap bmpImg = i.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);
        bmpImg =SetBrightness(bmpImg,-60);
        //Log.i("after Bitmap bmpImg",""+imgPath);
        Mat srcMat = new Mat ( bmpImg.getHeight(), bmpImg.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
        Bitmap myBitmap32 = bmpImg.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bmpImg, srcMat);

        //convert to gray scale and save image
        Mat gray = new Mat(srcMat.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
        //Imgproc.cvtColor(srcMat, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY,4);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(srcMat, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);
        //write bitmap
        Boolean grayBool = Highgui.imwrite(imgPath + "gray.jpg", gray);             
        Imgproc.medianBlur(gray, gray,51);      
        Utils.matToBitmap(gray, bmpImg);

        //thresholding
        Mat threshed = new Mat(bmpImg.getWidth(),bmpImg.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
        Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(gray, threshed, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 75, 5);//15, 8 were original tests. Casey was 75,10//(smoothed, threshed, 250, 250, 0);
        Core.bitwise_not(threshed, threshed);
        Boolean threshedBool = Highgui.imwrite(imgPath + "threshed.jpg", threshed); 
        Utils.matToBitmap(threshed, bmpImg);

        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(threshed, threshed, new org.opencv.core.Size(9, 9), 2, 2);
        Utils.matToBitmap(threshed, bmpImg);

        //erosion
        Mat eroded = new Mat(bmpImg.getWidth(),bmpImg.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
        Imgproc.erode(threshed, eroded, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new org.opencv.core.Size(15, 15)));
        Utils.matToBitmap(eroded, bmpImg);
        //write bitmap
        Boolean boolEroded = Highgui.imwrite(imgPath + "eroded.jpg", eroded);


        //smoothing
        //Imgproc.GaussianBlur(threshed, threshed, new org.opencv.core.Size(3,3), 50);
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(edge, threshed, new org.opencv.core.Size(9, 9), 2, 2);
        Utils.matToBitmap(threshed, bmpImg);

        //hough circles
        Mat circles = new Mat();

        Imgproc.HoughCircles( eroded, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1, eroded.rows()/8, 200,100, eroded.cols()/25, eroded.cols()/6 );
        //Imgproc.HoughCircles( threshed, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1, threshed.rows()/8,100, 80, 10, 100);
```

Please assist. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There can be  a number of approaches, some options you can try:

1> If you are sure of the kind of pills that you can expect, you can train your own HAAR classifiers. Read this tutorial to figure out how to do so: http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html
You can find even more tutorials, if you look around

2> From the looks of it, your pills seems to be circular or elliptical in shape. Why not use Houghs Circle Transform to find the circles? Check more here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html

3> Chroma Keying. I doubt that you will have pills which are green in colour. Put all your pills on a green chart paper and then you can very easily remove the background (the table) in your image. All you are left with are the pills and then it's just a matter of finding external contours to figure out the number of pills. For that matter, understand that the green colour is not a necessity, as long as your can maintain a huge colour difference between the background and the pills and the background has a single colour.

Comment: i also try houghcircle see my code on above but i am not able to detect any ellipse.

Comment: I suggest 1 and 3 then. Do consider 3. It's both fast and effective.

Comment: i am using option 3 but i am not able to count no. of pills. i am able to identify capsules but i am not able to count capsules. please help how to count no of pills

Comment: Obtain a binary mat of your image, where white represents the identified capsules. After that use findContours to figure out the number of pills.

Comment: as per our discussion , i am use findContours then after find area and drawContours but camera distance give different number pills from different distance. how to solve distance problem ? you have any idea regarding this.